# Could this unexpected bias in the distribution of consecutive primes have any impact on the security of encryption algorithms?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

In a recent paper a quite unexpected result about a new pattern in prime numbers emerged:

[Unexpected biases in the distribution of consecutive primes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1603.03720)
by Oliver, R. J. L.; Soundararajan, K. (Submitted on 11 Mar 2016)

> While the sequence of primes is very well distributed in the reduced
>   residue classes (mod $q$), the distribution of pairs of consecutive
>   primes among the permissible $ϕ(q)^2$ pairs of reduced residue classes
>   (mod $q$) is surprisingly erratic. This paper proposes a conjectural
>   explanation for this phenomenon, based on the Hardy-Littlewood
>   conjectures. The conjectures are then compared to numerical data, and
>   the observed fit is very good.

**My question**
Could this result have any impact on the security of encryption algorithms which are based on prime numbers?

Comment: I am not really an expert in encryption; still I have never heard of algorithms that would depend on pairs of consecutive primes.

Comment: Hard to see how.

Comment: @Lucia: My experience tells me that *most* (if not all) patterns can be exploited - sometimes in the most unexpected ways... I think this one needs careful consideration.

Comment: If there are any algorithms out there which use consecutive primes, they have a bigger problem. If $x = p_k p_{k+1}$, then $x-p_k$ is usually $\approx (1/2) \log p_k \approx (1/4) \log x$. So we can factor $x$ by trying $\log x$ divisors near $\sqrt{x}$, a polynomial algorithm.

Comment: I might wonder about the following.  Some algorithms need a large random prime (e.g. RSA).  A naive way to get a random prime is to generate a large random number N, and then apply a primality test to N, N+1, N+2, ... until a prime is found.  By such an algorithm, if two consecutive primes are very close together, the second one would be less likely to be chosen. So it seems like knowing something about consecutive primes would give you information about how such "random" primes would actually be distributed.

Comment: The result being described is agnostic to whether the consecutive primes are closer together or farther apart than average.

Comment: Related: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/117440

Comment: Here the discovery is described as "beautiful", but on security.stackexchange.com it is described as "absolute rubbish". Which is it?

Comment: @PaulBaker the user saying this on [security.se] quite clearly had not even read the pop-science description of the result. I would not assign overly much weight to this, except maybe as a warning of the dangers of half-knowledge and for other sociological reasons.

Comment: I am somewhat surprised that no mention seems to be made in that paper of the distribution of the differences between consecutive primes. The number they get show a bias towards consecutive primes with unequal remainders mod $3$ (i.e. whose difference is not divisible by $3$), which would not seem that unexpected if one expects the differences between primes to be uniform (and I don't know whether it should be more natural to expect the pairs to be uniform or the differences to be uniform).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This discovery is beautiful, but it's unlikely to have any impact on cryptography. Of course this lack of relevance is a matter of speculation/opinion, not proven mathematical fact, but these sorts of correlations between consecutive primes just haven't come up in cryptography to my knowledge, because there seems to be no value in using extremely close primes in any cryptosystem. It's basically orthogonal to what cryptographers care about. Of course it's always worth learning more about the primes, and it's hard to predict where it might lead in the future, but this paper raises no special cause for concern in cryptography.

Comment: If anything use of nearby primes is discouraged, since an efficient attack would consist of trying to solve $p(p+2)=n,$ say, where $n=p_i p_j$ is the RSA modulus. And random choice would give you primes of a given bitlength, which means they are typically apart by $2^{n-2}$ if your bitlength is $n$ and they're chosen independently at random https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Key_generation

Answer (score 4):

There's another discussion of the bias on [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1698116/mathematicians-shocked-to-find-pattern-in-prime-numbers).  The phenomenon is not limited to consecutive primes, but its repulsion effect seems to be attenuated (or masked by noise) too quickly to have powerful consequences.  Oliver and Soundararajan note there may be implications for semiprimes, which would be of cryptographic interest.

There are hints that the prime numbers are leaking information to nearby composites.  It's conceivable that one might be able to factorize an arbitrary composite quickly by collecting enough information from the primes near it.